# How to make Xenon 1900 make ENTER with each LF on Windows OS

Tags: barcode-scanner, honeywell

We have QR codes whose content is presented in the form of:

```
XXXXXX
YYYYYY
ZZZZZZ
```

The line break is the LF (Line Feed) character because it's made in Linux. The problem is that when we scan this QR code with Xenon 1900 and Windows machine, it has only one row:

```
XXXXXXYYYYYYZZZZZZ
```

I would like to ask is there a way to get it back on Windows?

Comment: If it is the content of the QR barcode, it will not be possible to change it by setting the scanner or device driver/OS. The replacement of such data content must be done by the notified application.

Comment: It's a small possibility, but this article may be helpful. [How to enter a function key / arrow key / Carriage Return / TAB / Page Down by scanning a bar code?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-enter-a-function-key-arrow-key-Carriage-Return-TAB-Page-Down-by-scanning-a-bar-code)

Comment: @kunif thanks for your guide, and so sad when checking the guide, it said "LF" is "reserved" or "f18" key :( It's really a dead-end now